# Generate variables with prescribe probabability

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to generate data with some probability. Below you can see one example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_categories = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(a=["M", "F"], size=100, p=[0.7, 0.3]),
columns = ['gender'])
df_categories

df_categories['gender'].value_counts()
```

[image]

So far so good. Now I want to repeat this but with following categories: `"TypeOfIncome_1","TypeOfIncome_2","TypeOfIncome_3","TypeOfIncome_4","TypeOfIncome_5","TypeOfIncome_6","TypeOfIncome_7","TypeOfIncome_8"`

Each of these categories have some specific probability `[0.6,0.2,0.05,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.03]` or in total 1.
Similar to the example above I want to create a table with these probabilities

```
df_categories = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(["TypeOfIncome_1","TypeOfIncome_2","TypeOfIncome_3","TypeOfIncome_4","TypeOfIncome_5","TypeOfIncome_6","TypeOfIncome_7","TypeOfIncome_8"], 100, [0.6,0.2,0.05,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.03])
, columns = ['source_of_income'])
df_categories

df_categories['source_of_income'].value_counts()
```

[image]

This example shows that TypeOfIncome_1, instead to have the largest frequency in the data frame, this variable has the smallest and so on. So can anybody help me how to create data with this probability `[0.6,0.2,0.05,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.03,0.03]` ?

Comment: Add the named argument `p=[....]` before the list of probabilities . Your implementation is interpreted as third argument `replace=truthy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in this way:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#---- set the population parameters
Ntrials = 10       # for testing
Ntrials = 1000000  # for production
p0 = [0.6, 0.2, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03]
Nrange = len(p0)

#---- generate and evaluate the population
trials = np.random.choice(Nrange, Ntrials, p=p0)
histo = plt.hist(trials, bins=Nrange)
abs_histo   = histo[0]
bins_bounds = histo[1]
print("abs_histo  ", abs_histo);print()
print("bins_bounds", bins_bounds);print()
plt.show()

#---- generate the name list
name_list = np.array(["TypeOfIncome_" + str(i+1) for i in range(Nrange)])
print("name_list", name_list);print()


#---- generate pandas data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Income_distribution':abs_histo }, index=name_list)
df
```

this gives

```
abs_histo   [599502. 200493.  50267.  29829.  30020.  29924.  30001.  29964.]

bins_bounds [0.    0.875 1.75  2.625 3.5   4.375 5.25  6.125 7.   ]
```

[image]

```
Income_distribution
TypeOfIncome_1  599502.0
TypeOfIncome_2  200493.0
TypeOfIncome_3  50267.0
TypeOfIncome_4  29829.0
TypeOfIncome_5  30020.0
TypeOfIncome_6  29924.0
TypeOfIncome_7  30001.0
TypeOfIncome_8  29964.0
```